# AWS Cloudformation Lambda S3 - Circular Dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

**Thanks in advance!**

So I have created this Cloudformation template below and have a circular dependency error.. I know what is causing the error, but cannot think of a solution for what I'm trying to achieve..

Which is;

- Create a lambda function that has a two environment variables for two buckets I need to use in the functions code
- Create two s3 buckets, one for a file input and one for a file output
- Create a trigger that calls the lambda function when an object is added to the 1st bucket

Here is my code:

```
      "lambda": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "DependsOn": [
                "s3accessrole",
                "s3rolepolicies",
                "bucket1"
            ],
            "Properties": {
                "Code": {
                    "S3Bucket": "resource-bucket",
                    "S3Key": "filepath/function.zip"
                },
                "Role": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "s3accessrole",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "Timeout": 60,
                "Handler": "function.handler",
                "Runtime": "nodejs6.10",
                "MemorySize": 1024,
                "Environment": {
                    "Variables": {
                        "bucket1": {
                            "Ref": "bucket1"
                        },
                        "bucket2": {
                            "Ref": "bucket2"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "XXXX"
                }
            }
        },
        "bucket1": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {
                "AccessControl": "Private",
                "LifecycleConfiguration": {
                    "Rules": [
                        {
                            "ExpirationInDays": "1",
                            "Id": "delete images/",
                            "Status": "Enabled"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "VersioningConfiguration": {
                    "Status": "Suspended"
                },
                "NotificationConfiguration": {
                    "LambdaConfigurations": [
                        {
                            "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                            "Function": {
                                "Ref": "lambda"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "XXXX"
                }
            }
        },
        "lambdaperm": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
            "Properties": {
                "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "FunctionName": {
                    "Ref": "lambda"
                },
                "Principal": "s3.amazonaws.com",
                "SourceAccount": {
                    "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                },
                "SourceArn": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        ":",
                        [
                            "arn",
                            "aws",
                            "s3",
                            "",
                            "",
                            {
                                "Ref": "bucket1"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "XXXX"
                }
            }
        },
        "bucket2": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {
                "AccessControl": "Private",
                "LifecycleConfiguration": {
                    "Rules": [
                        {
                            "ExpirationInDays": "1",
                            "Id": "delete images/",
                            "Status": "Enabled"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "VersioningConfiguration": {
                    "Status": "Suspended"
                }
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "XXXX"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why does your Lambda code need the name of the two buckets? If it is using one as input and one as output, then the incoming Event will provide the name of the input bucket. Therefore, you could (1) Create the output bucket, (2) Create the Lambda function with a ref to the output bucket, (3) Create the input bucket with a Trigger pointing to the Lambda function. No circles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incoming event from the first bucket in the lambda function contained the name used for that bucket and thus I didnt need to create an environment variable.

Comment: This is true; however, you need to make sure that the Lambda execution role (what you have as s3accessrole) isn't itself defined in the CloudFormation template with permissions that specifically name the S3 bucket (what you have as bucket1).

You can still define it to grant specific S3 methods, e.g. s3:GetObject, but the Resource will need to be '*'; unfortunately you won't be able to lock it down to just that bucket, which is probably what you would have wanted here.